# Constructing a swept solid

Tags: bevel

Please see the .blend file attached.

[image]

I want to 'sweep' a profile along a path to create a solid that can then be exported as an stl file for 3d printing. Unfortunately, I have several issues...

1. the ends of the resulting 'solid' are uncapped. While it's easy to select and alt-F the end vertices, it seems there must be a simpler way
2. I construct the 'solid' using the bevel modifier. But, regardless of what method I use, I always end up with overlapping meshes - as highlighted in the following image. The resulting stl file has 'bad edges' and I think this may be a reason:

[image]

3. Finally, the resulting mesh seems to have far too many faces, but I can't see an automatic way to reduce this. Again, this results in a large blend file and a huge stl file.

I know it's bad form to post multiple questions, but these are in a way all aspects of the same problem: How to construct a valid stl file.

Anyway, as always, any thoughts on resolving any of the above hugely appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion/56352#56352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me unpack this one by one :)

**1. Fill caps**
You need to check *Fill Caps* in *Geometry > Bevel > Fill Caps*

[image]

**2. Overlapping geometry**
This is a result of beveling multiple curves into one point.
You'll have to manually clean it up, or use the Boolean modifier, etc.

**3. Too many faces**
To adjust the amount of faces change the values in *Shape > Preview/render resolution*.
You can do this for both of your curve shapes.

[image]

Here is the edited .blendfile
[image]

Comment: I don't think my profile has any overlapping vertices. Can you elaborate !?!

Comment: Thanks - that's a huge help, and that definitely creates a printable file now, so while the overlapping meshes are still there, it doesn't actually seem to be an issue for the resulting file. That said , I'm still really struggling to see what was wrong with my geometry.

Comment: There were two free floating vertices, in your Bevel curve. They prevented the *Fill Caps* function from working properly. And also created more overlapping geometry.

Comment: How did you know/spot that?

Comment: It was just a lucky guess :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks again; it kind of works now (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/P6GQJno2) although I guess you'll need the Sverchok module to see it. It still fails when 'duplicated' beyond a certain point, but perhasps that's a question for another day...

Comment: I can't check the file now, but feel free to ask a new question :).

Comment: Actually, it must be some glitch on my workstation, because it works just fine on my laptop