# Sverchok. A file which worked fine 2.8* no longer works in 2.91.0

Tags: sverchok

With reference to a previous post of mine ([Sverchok. Duplicating an object along a path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164178/sverchok-duplicating-an-object-along-a-path)), the linked file at that question (grille6) no longer seems to work in 2.91.0.

I've replaced the 'deprecated' Polyline Viewer with another viewer of the same name, but so far, no luck.

What am I missing?

* the previous version might have been 2.79 - I can't actually remember

Comment: Do you need to update to 2.91? Keep in mind that some addons (like the one you mention) might need updating on newer versions. It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: @susu I think I do - in order to take advantage of some other features.

Comment: Issues with add-ons are easier to solve by contacting the developers directly. Try downloading the most current version from github.

Comment: I have, and the developers hang around here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reget object in

reget path

switch POLY in viewer

https://yadi.sk/d/li_uYmjR2dLsxA

try this

Comment: Thanks - that works - although I can't see what's different from what I tried !?!?! But thanks again.

Comment: @Strawberry instead of thanking in comments, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @susu Don't worry, I will in due course.