# Boolean operations in Sverchok

Tags: sverchok

I'm revisiting this project after a considerable hiatus (well, you only need to print grilles so otften): [Sverchok. Duplicating an object along a path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164178/sverchok-duplicating-an-object-along-a-path).

It works very well now, but I'd like to automate one final step...

At present, I 'manually' (by which I mean 'using a non-node based solution') perform two Boolean operations on the resulting objects - to UNION the small cylinders and SUBTRACT the large cylinders.

[image]

I guess it must be possible to automate this process too (presumably using a List Modifier), but I'm struggling to get that to work.

Here's a Blend of the latest incarnation - tweaked to work with 2.9x...

[image]

Help?

Answer (score 3):

To perform Boolean Operations in Sverchok you have three alternatives:

1. Using CSG Boolean Node: It is pretty slow and sometimes produces not watertight meshes and ugly topology. Also it has some limitations, please check the [Warnings section of the nodes documentation](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/nodes/modifier_make/csg_booleanMK2.rst)
2. Use a Exec Node Mod to apply standard Blender Boolean modifiers to created objects [check this comment](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/3678#issuecomment-722329785): This option is pretty simple but requires a little of coding.
3. Use the Solid Nodes, that require FreeCad, to perform the operations more info [here](http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/solids.html): Once you have installed the dependencies this should be the easiest and more robust solution

Comment: I'm trying the CSG Boolean (2) node. I can get it to work with two simple objects - two cubes say, but one of my meshes is a bevel applied to a path

Comment: The CSG Boolean Node fails in some cases,I added to the answer a link to the documentation of the node where the limitations are explained