# How to convert mesh modeled in Blender to IGES CAD format or similar?

Tags: export, file-format

I used Blender to construct a very complicated geometry that I would now like to use for Computational Fluid Dynamics simulations. One of the Finite Volume meshers that I'm testing does not do a very good job with STLs, is there a way of converting my smooth surface mesh into an IGES CAD file, or similar?

Comment: If you search for IGES in this forum, you'll find several possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, GBY2KE, I hope you don't mind my edit. Hopefully this way the question will get more attention sooner.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213269/can-blender-be-used-to-send-to-a-factory-to-create-silicone-products-mass-produ

Comment: Thanks Martynas, your suggestion was good. I installed an add-on but was having some problems, especially with groups of parented objects and Boolean modifiers.